# Login server using Git Bash on Windows: how to enable scrolling?

Tags: git-bash, gnu-screen

I'm using Git Bash on Windows to login a remote server. When I create a screen, I was unable to activate scrolling using `Ctrl + A + Esc` as in :

> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40242/scroll-inside-screen-or-pause-output

How can I do this? Please help me, thank you very much.

UPDATE: When I create a screen I use `screen -S screen_name`
When I connect to it I use, `screen -ls`, then `screen -x screen_id`

Comment: Please include your `screen` invocation.  Not sure it'll matter, but somebody who knows `screen` may need it.

Comment: @StephenNewell I have done as you requested

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to see if a [screen emulator like ConEmu](https://superuser.com/a/667594/141) offer a similar feature, without having to rely on the msys2 bash session.

Other option: if you are on the latest Windows 10, use a [WSL bash session](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux), which is effectively a Linux session, with Git for Linux in it, and the screen command as well.